# working of pointer to functions in c

Tags: c, function, pointers

Please look at the code following:-

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int sum ( int b, int a){
 return (a+b);
  }
 int main(){
 int (* funptr)( int , int ) = sum;
 int a = ( * funptr )( 4,5);
 int b = funptr (4,5);
 printf("%d\n%d",a,b);
 return 1;
 }
```

Is there any difference between the two function calling via pointer,one is

```
int a = ( * funptr )( 4,5);
```

and another is

```
int b = funptr (4,5);
```

As i have compiled this code and result is same in both the cases.Is this means that these are equivalent?

Comment: They are identical, but personally I always use the `(*funcptr)(...)` form to make it explicit that I am dereferencing a pointer. Makes it clearer to the reader that it isn't a function with that actual name.

Comment: @Dave so dereferencing the function pointer yields the same value as without dereferencing?

Comment: Yes. As I said, "They are identical"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of function pointer:

`Function Pointer` is very flexible to use..
You can put value into it with or without the `&` operator, and call the stored function through pointer with or without `*` operator.

e.g,

```
int (* funptr)( int , int ) = sum;   // or int (* funptr)( int , int ) = &sum;
int a = ( * funptr )( 4,5);          // or int a = funptr( 4,5);
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: int (* funptr)( int , int ) = *sum; //or **sum is also equivalent?

Comment: Yes... You can put as many `*` as you want before `sum` it all will result same...

Comment: i have seen these statement written before few times what that mean by *sum as so what is the difference between sum and *sum and **sum?

Comment: if, as your previous example, `sum` is a function, and it is asked to differentiate `sum` and `*sum`, in this case actually `*sum` makes no sense, compiler just ignores the `*` operator in such case..

Answer (score 2):

Due to historic differences how to take the address of a function, you can apply address of and dereference any time you want to a function name, without any effect whatsoever.

Also, dereferencing a function pointer has no effect at all.

So, yes, your examples are equivalent.

Comment: so these two calling statements are equivalent?

Comment: yes, they are equivalent. BTW: Get the standard: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: int (* funptr)( int , int ) = *sum; //or **sum is also equivalent?

Comment: They are not equivalent to previous examples, but your two new examples are equivalent to each other...

Comment: oh! conflict between your and deb_rider comment please look at the comment of his answer.

Comment: Hm, clarified my comment just before your post, now all clear?

Comment: Yes! that what i meant,i have seen these statement written before few times what that mean by *sum as so what is the difference between sum and *sum and **sum?

Comment: As i said, the dereference has no effect => none.